# Annotate / draw on a HTML5 slideshow

Tags: html, slideshow

I'm using the HTML5 slideshow library [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/) on OSX to teach programming.

What's still missing for me is a way to **highlight something on a slide via simple drawings** (e.g. encircle something).

*Is there any way to do this (javascript or Mac app)?*

PS: I tried a few run-of-the-mill apps which were very inconvenient to use during a presentation.

Thanks!

EDIT: maybe something in terms of using an overlay canvas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing like this built into reveal.js but, as you suggest in the edit, it would be possible by overlaying a canvas element or SVG animation.

Personally I'd recommend not going for the hand drawn style and instead highlighting elements using standard CSS and [fragments](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/15). Elements that are given the 'fragment' class will be stepped through by reveal.js, each fragment is given a 'visible' class when it should be highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

I think [DazzleSketch](http://csev.github.io/dazzleSketch/) does what you're looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-ogf0ZDpj4

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no easy way to achieve this. Everything in reveal.js relies on standard HTML5 and there is no such thing as freehand drawing inside HTML.

Comment: I thought maybe a canvas can be used, put on top of the slide. Isn't there maybe a library for this? (updated question to reflect this)

Comment: Generally I would say "yes" ... but in that case the canvas will always receive the click events in order to enable drawing. The underlying links on the slide would no longer work.